# Pass multiple values of the same parameter for search method

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, search

I would like to update my search function, so that it would accept additional parameters, which will be builed dinamically with checkboxes(let's say for a location NY AND Tokio AND Berlin). For now, my controller accepts page number and a search string, which are called with Ajax for infinate pagination.

So my search link is now like: /TopEventsul?searchString=HouseParty

and would like to add more search functions like: /TopEventsul?searchString=HouseParty&Location=London&Location=Tokio

Can u please point me to the right direction or maybe give me some examples?

Bellow is my controller function

```
// GET: Ul
    public ActionResult Index(int? pageNum, string searchString)
    {        
        pageNum = pageNum ?? 0;
        ViewBag.IsEndOfRecords = false;
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            var customers = GetRecordsForPage(pageNum.Value);
            ViewBag.IsEndOfRecords = (customers.Any()) && ((pageNum.Value * RecordsPerPage) >= customers.Last().Key);
            return PartialView("_TopEventLi", customers);
        }
        else
        {
            LoadAllTopEventsToSession(searchString);
            ViewBag.TopEvents = GetRecordsForPage(pageNum.Value);
            return View("Index");
        }
    }

    public void LoadAllTopEventsToSession(string searchString)
    {
        var students = from s in db.TopEvents
                       select s;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            students = students.Where(s => s.Location.Contains(searchString)
                                   || s.Title.Contains(searchString));
        }
        var customers = students.ToList();
        int custIndex = 1;
        Session["TopEventi"] = customers.ToDictionary(x => custIndex++, x => x);
        ViewBag.TotalNumberCustomers = customers.Count();
    }

    public Dictionary<int, TopEvents> GetRecordsForPage(int pageNum)
    {
        Dictionary<int, TopEvents> customers = (Session["TopEventi"] as Dictionary<int, TopEvents>);

        int from = (pageNum * RecordsPerPage);
        int to = from + RecordsPerPage;

        return customers
            .Where(x => x.Key > from && x.Key <= to)
            .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
    }
```

Regards!

Comment: Add a parameter `IEnumerable<string> Location`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have Location as fixed parameter, so you can simply do like these,

```
  public ActionResult Index(int? pageNum, string searchString, IEnumerable<string> Location)  
  {   
    // Your code  
  }
```

if you have any other parameters you can also add them, for exa.
your parameter is param and it's type is int then

```
public ActionResult Index(int? pageNum, string searchString, int param)  
  {   
    // Your code  
  }
```

//Ajax Call for Index

```
function testAjax() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Content("~/Your-Controller/Index")",
            data: "pageNum=" + your data for pageNum + "&searchString=" + your searchString + "&param=" + param,
            dataType: "json",
            type: "Post",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            beforeSend: function () {
                //Code for before send whatever you have to do.
            },
            success: function (data) {
               //Your code when all ok
            },
            error: function (response) {
                //Your code when error ocure
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                //your code for failure 
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        })
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: May I call those search methods with Ajax, that the page wont' reload(It works, but page reloads)? I have wrote a form from Proffesional ASP.net MVC 5 book-musicstore, but the page reloads... Should I open a new questions for this part?

Comment: no, you not need to add one more question. it's call ajax partial call. let me give you an example code of how to call these methods via ajax...

Comment: give me some more time i need to create those type of function.

Comment: Thank you :) Looking forward

Comment: i cannot add a comment with more then some letter, so i cannot post my code here..

Comment: Thank you, but I get 500 result on fiddler. My request header:POST /TopEventsUl/Index HTTP/1.1, and Invalid JSON primitive: pageNum, and so is if I only use searchString. Can be a problem here with Json or data field for url.content?

Comment: are you using a firebug to debugg? if yes then you can see your json on it.

Comment: Sorry, but i can't see json

Host: localhost:51540
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: sl,en-GB;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://localhost:51540/TopEventsUl/Index/=?UTF-8?B?RDpcU2VydmlzXGV2ZW50aTEyM1NlcnZpY2VcVG9wRXZlbnRzVWxcSW5kZXg=?=
Content-Length: 17
Cookie: username=0; ASP.NET_SessionId=ttvjc0uoprgq3snssacur2rh
Connection: keep-alive

my head request

Comment: can you give me your team viewer?

Comment: 891 192 347
Pass: 9612

Comment: please generate pass again,

Comment: p6m96h is my new pass